# Different output of GoogLeNet Model in Virtual Machine and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am using GoogleNet model for binary classification of images. Earlier, I was using the virtual machine and now I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Both are giving me different results. I tried to find out a lot where is the problem but couldn't pinpoint it.

I have trained two models separately one in Ubuntu 14.04 and another in the virtual machine. Both models are using CPU. cuDNN is not being used in both. Regarding BLAS library I am using default ATLAS.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: how different the results? did you started training from a trained model ("finetuning") or from scratch (random weights)? is it possible that the random seed of caffe was different in the two runs?

Comment: In both cases, I started the training from scratch and with the same parameters. And the difference in the results are huge more than 20%.

Comment: have you fixed [`random_seed`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L207) in your `solver.prototxt` to the same seed in both cases explicitly?

Comment: No, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you started your training [from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979481/output-of-googlenet-model?noredirect=1#comment61519227_36979481) in both cases and you did not explicitly fixed [`random_seed`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L207) parameter in your `solver.prototxt` it is very likely that caffe initialized your model with different random weights for each of the two training processes. Starting from different points is very likely to end with differently trained models.
If you are concerned about possible differences in caffe between the two architectures, try repeat the training but with **the same** `random_seed` parameter in `solver.prototxt`.

Comment: So, shall I use the below line to set the random seed. 
radom_seed = 10
is this command right? or do I need to assign the some other value.

Comment: @AshutoshSingla the correct syntax would be `random_seed: 10` or any integer number for that matter. My personal favorite is 310 ;)

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help. I will do the same the will update you.

Comment: @AshutoshSingla well, it might be more appropriate to wait with "Accepting" this answer to the results of your new experiment... (not that I'm complaining)

Comment: I set random_seed: 1 in my solver file and still I am getting the different results. I also looked into the issue. I found this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/bsp34yOcEZo

Comment: @AshutoshSingla how different are your results? can this difference be explained as a "random perturbation" or is there a *significant* difference?

Comment: In Linux : True Positive 99  True Negative 23
In Virtual Machine : True Positive 91 True Negative 48

Comment: @AshutoshSingla shouldn't they add upto the same value i.e. 99 + 23 and 91 + 48 should have given the same result...

Comment: @Shai - Does setting `random_seed` also helps ensure that the total time taken to train the network will remain same if I run it today and then tomorrow for same network parameters?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil I don't know. My guess is that run time is not affected by the actual value of parameters/data